# How to make bootstrap columns for mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason, my columns will only work on web browser / tablets.

However, when I am trying to view my website on my Droid 4, the images I used are not displayed in a row (divided by columns).  What exactly do I need to do to make these columns work?

css:

```
 <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style type="text/css">


     @media (max-width: 767px) { .row-fluid .image { width:50%; float:left; } }
    </style>
```

Images not in a row when viewed on a mobile device:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <img class="img-circle" src="img/SunnyD.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="50" height="50">

    </div> 
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <img class="img-circle" src="img/lindt.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="50" height="50">

    </div> 
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <img  src="img/tmlogo.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="50" height="50">

    </div> 
  </div><!-- /.row -->
```

When viewed on mobile, I see a new row for each image. When viewed on browser, I see all the images in one row (which is what I want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add to the class attributes the values

`col-xs-` - Extra small devices Phones (<768px)

`col-sm-` - Small devices Tablets (≥768px)

`col-md-` - Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)

For example,

```
....
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-1 col-sm-2 col-md-3">
....
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: It's interesting how lg-4 creates columns for md and sm devices, yet not xs.

Answer (score 1):

Change `.col-lg-4` to `.col-xs-4`.